# Mobile website - how to select contact

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web

There are many things to do with mobile website, i can for example open the sms app
with

```
<a href="sms:12345678?body=hello">SMS</a>
```

is there a way in javascript to make the user select a contact from his phone book?